# How to configure liferay to generate relative URL instead of absolute URL

Tags: liferay-6

Liferay is generating absolute URLS like "http://portal-sit.xxx.com/web/woodmac/home-page?p_p_id=MyDataTools_WAR_woodmacportal&#034;  from code . 
We want these URL's  relative like "/web/woodmac/home-page?p_p_id=MyDataTools_WAR_woodmacportal".

Any idea how to achieve  this.

Comment: I don't think it's developed yet even if it's a simple functionality. Here's an open issue  : https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-32097